# Add feature to postgis layer with sequenced id using pyqgis

Tags: postgis, pyqgis

Using python, I want to add a feature into a postgis layer that has a PK generated by a sequence.

layer (id [PK], field1, field2)

```
with edit(layer):
            fields = layer.pendingFields()
            new_feat = QgsFeature(fields)
            new_feat[1] = 'text1'
            new_feat[2] = 'text2'

            layer.addFeatures([new_feat])
```

But I get an error saying the value is too long for the type of the id attribute

Question: How can I assign the next value of the postgis sequence to the id?

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
with edit(layer):
    fields = layer.pendingFields()
    new_feat = QgsFeature(fields)
    newFeat.setAttributes([NULL, 'text 1', 'text 2'])

    layer.addFeatures([new_feat])
```

Comment: I tried already but it doesn't work. I get the same error

Comment: It's strange that an explicit NULL is returning a "too long" message. What specific constraints do you have on the PK and can you create a feature on the layer without using PyQGIS?

Comment: Indeed! Yes I can add a feature in QGIS, or with PyQGIS if I give the value of the next val manually. I have a sequence generated by a function.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `with edit(layer): ` with `layer.startEditing()`

Comment: Yes that is what I had before, but it didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

This post gives the solution: [How to create a QgsFeature with default attributes?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197866/how-to-create-a-qgsfeature-with-default-attributes)

Can anyone mark this question has a duplicate?