# Creating new layer with all attributes inherited from original layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, vector-layer, geometry-conversion

Let's assume there is a polygon layer called *'test2'* with its attribute table, see the image below.

[image: input]

With the code below I am creating a new layer as centroids of original features

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs={}&index=yes".format(layer.crs().authid()), "centroids", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    new_geom = feat.geometry().centroid()
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
    provider.addFeature(new_feat)
    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

and I achieve what I intended to, see the image below, but only in terms of geometries.

[image: result]

My question is: how to get all the attributes (`"id"`, "`X_East"`, and `"Y_North"`) from the original layer and bring them into a new layer?

I have seen this thread: [Creating QgsFeature with default attributes using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/197866/99589), but it did not work:

```py
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    new_feat = QgsVectorLayerUtils.createFeature(layer)
    new_geom = feat.geometry().centroid()
    new_feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
    provider.addFeature(new_feat)
```

Moreover, I do not understand how to transfer all attributes at once, not just one by one.

I am aware of the [`"native:centroids"`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#centroids), which can simplify my work, however, I want to achieve the desired output without application of any geoalgorithm.

---

**References:**

- [Reading attribute values using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54057/reading-attribute-values-using-pyqgis)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reviewed your code and added just a few lines:

1. add the source fields to the centroids layer (`addition 1`)

   The [`QgsVectorLayer`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#module-QgsVectorLayer) class contains the [`fields()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.fields) and [`updateFields()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.updateFields) methods.

   The [`QgsVectorDataProvider`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Vector/QgsVectorDataProvider.html) class has the [`addAttributes()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Vector/QgsVectorDataProvider.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorDataProvider.addAttributes) method.
2. copy the source feature attributes to the new feature (`addition 2`)

   The [`QgsFeature`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Feature/QgsFeature.html#module-QgsFeature) class possesses the [`setAttributes()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Feature/QgsFeature.html#qgis.core.QgsFeature.setAttributes) method.

Here the complete working code :

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

vl = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs={}&index=yes".format(layer.crs().authid()), "centroids", "memory")
provider = vl.dataProvider()

### addition 1
provider.addAttributes(layer.fields())
vl.updateFields()
###

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    new_geom = feat.geometry().centroid()
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
    ### addition 2
    new_feat.setAttributes(feat.attributes())
    ###
    provider.addFeature(new_feat)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)
```

The code above will result into:

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Getting field names of layer using PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347126/getting-field-names-of-layer-using-pyqgis)