# Create Buffer but keep original Attribute table

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I want to create a buffer around a number of features. It is important for me to keep the attributes of the features in the new buffer.shp layer. When I try to write a new VectorLayer with a QgsVectorFileWriter, I do get the buffered polygons and also the fields of the original layer get copied over, however the attribute table stays empty.

How can I copy over the attributes of the original layer to the buffer layer?

As you can see I already tried to load the attributes using the . attributes() method on the QgsFeature object and setting the attributes. However I feel I am missing something here.

```
for f in feats:
    attributes = f.attributes()
    f.setAttributes(attributes)
```

See full code below:

```
path = '/Volumes/VAW_ETH-Z/M.Thesis/data/geospatial/'

# load filtered sgi
sgi_filtered = QgsVectorLayer(path + 'sgi_filtered.shp')

## Create buffer around filtered sgi
outFn = path + 'gl_buffer3.shp'
bufferDist = 50 # in map units

fields = sgi_filtered.fields()
feats = sgi_filtered.getFeatures()

writer = QgsVectorFileWriter(
            outFn,
            'utf-8',
            fields,
            QgsWkbTypes.Polygon,
            sgi_filtered.sourceCrs(), # loads the reference system of the source feature
            'ESRI Shapefile')

for f in feats:
    attributes = f.attributes()
    f.setAttributes(attributes)
    geom = f.geometry()
    buff = geom.buffer(bufferDist, 5)
    f.setGeometry(buff)
    
    writer.addFeature(f)
```

Screenshot of the Attribute Table below (it shows the fields but no attributes):

[image: Empty Attribute table. The fields are displayed however no attributes have been added.]

Comment: Check this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/429034/creating-new-layer-with-all-attributes-inherited-from-original-layer-using-pyqgi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `del writer` after `for` loop.

```
for f in feats:
    attributes = f.attributes()
    f.setAttributes(attributes)
    geom = f.geometry()
    buff = geom.buffer(bufferDist, 5)
    f.setGeometry(buff)
    
    writer.addFeature(f)

del writer
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! Can you tell me the reason why It is important to delete the writer?

Comment: You need to delete the writer to flush features to disk.